# Entity Framework - foreign key property not changed after db.SaveChanges();

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a database(code first) with 2 tables User and Category. Every user is assigned to one category:

This code works:

```csharp
User userEntity = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == model.UserId);
Category categoryEntity = db.Category.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == model.Category.CategoryId);
userEntity.Category = categoryEntity;
db.SaveChanges();
```

This code does not work:

```csharp
db.Entry(model).Entity.Category.CategoryId = model.Category.CategoryId;
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

My `DbContext` is:

```cs
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired<Category>(s => s.Category);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Why is that?

At first I had code that does not work marked as in the first example.

After a changes I corrected the error and my code works marked as second example.

I just want to know the reason..

Comment: 1 work or not? can you clarify? its contradicting with your last sentence

Comment: You should show the entity classes and only the code that "doesn't work" (+ explain what that means). The last couple of sentences make this a highly confusing question.

Answer (score 1):

your first code is not working because the `Category` property is a navigation property that represents the relationship between the `User` and `Category` entities, but it does not represent a column in the database.

you need to add this line `userEntity.CategoryId = categoryEntity.CategoryId;` in your first code

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to attach the change to your DBContext before saving change, something like this:

```cs
_context.Users.Attach(your_modifed_user_object);
```

By doing this, you tell Entity Framework (EF) that your object has a new change, and EF will be able to 'track' the change to generate the correct SQL command.

Note that you need to use `Attach` because your user object is an existing object in the database, so EF needs to track it.

More about `Attach` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state#attaching-an-existing-entity-to-the-context

Answer (score 0):

**For those who are curious.**

My problem was my model.

I changed my User model class to:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string Contact { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Now my model contains CategoryId, which can be set. Changes to this property changes whole Category property.
My working code is now:

```
db.Entry(model).Entity.CategoryId = model.Category.CategoryId;
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If the class didn't have `CategoryId` how could the second code fragment even run?